# Getting log4j warning but not called anywhere

Tags: java, logging, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am getting the following warnings in my console when I run my `testng` suites:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager)
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

We were using log4j previously but have since moved to a new logger. The project has had all references to log4j removed, but we are still getting these errors. We are using `Selenium Web Driver`, and it seems like we are getting these warnings on this line here:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

The only thing I can think of is that FirefoxDriver is asking for a `log4j` object or something and it is not receiving it, but the source code doesn't call for a `log4j`. Does anyone have any idea why we are getting these warnings? I am not too familiar with `log4j` and have just recently been brought on to the team. I have read things about log4j properties files, but we don't have any of those so I don't think it has anything to do with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log4j is being asked for a logger corresponding to

```
org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager
```

and the log message clearly show that log4j is still present somewhere deep inside.  For maven projects this is most likely a transient dependency which you explicitly must disable yourself.

The established convention is that this is the name of the class requesting the logger object, in case you want to investigate.

Comment: This makes sense. However, log4j is not being created anywhere in my project. We do not use log4j and don't want to create a log4j.properties file. My question is how to get rid of these warnings since, in theory, log4j shouldn't be called anywhere.

Comment: I see you edited your answer when i responded. I will take a look into this. The dependency issue is something I haven't considered.

Comment: After doing some digging around (and breaking my dependencies) it turns out that Selenium WebDriver uses log4j and it can't be turned off without breaking the project without making the log4j.properties file.

Comment: You may explicitly disable the dependency to remove log4j from your deployment and then add log4j-over-slf4j.jar to redirect to slf4j.  http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: This looks like the right kind of fix for our needs. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not called but it is still associated with in your project build library, remove it from there and remove the log4j xml aslo from the project build directory. Give it a try